# How to convert arbitrary string to valid React ComponentName

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, string, replace

I am trying to autogenerate a React component name from an arbitrary string using regular expressions.

The idea is to convert the string to PascalCase while ensuring the first character is always a letter.

Some testcases:

```
toComponentCase('hi there') // HiThere
toComponentCase(' lorem ipsum _ 123?') // LoremIpsum123
toComponentCase('_lor?em ipSum doll?er') // LoremIpSumDollEr
toComponentCase('123 some_component') // SomeComponent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with compact solution which seems to be technically correct:

```js
function toComponentCase(text) {
  return text.replace(/(?:^[^A-Za-z]*|[\W_]+)(.)?/g, (_, c) => c ? c.toUpperCase() : '')
}

console.log(toComponentCase('hi there'))
console.log(toComponentCase(' lorem ipsum _ 123?'))
console.log(toComponentCase('_lor?em ipSum doll?er'))
console.log(toComponentCase('123 some_component'))
```